# Which of these URL is better for SEO?

Tags: seo, google-search, url, site-structure

I am trying to restructure our website that is focus on Healthcare and could you please help me which of these two decisions for URL is better for SEO ? 
we present best providers for any healthcare procedures in each city and country.
here is an example of rhinoplasty procedure in turkey:

www.mywebsite.com/**en/rhinoplasty/turkey**

www.mywebsite.com/**en/rhinoplasty/rhinoplasty-turkey**

1-is it necessary to write exact focus keyword in last folder of URL? 
In this example, rhinoplasty is our **pillar page**, so it has so many cluster contents that link back to it, such as this procedures in each countries, ...

2-Is it necessary to put our main pillar pages in top level of URL? 
can we locate all pillar pages related to cosmetic surgeries inside cosmetic-surgery folder?

**Pillarpage:** www.mywebsite.com/**en/cosmetic-surgery/rhinoplasty**

www.mywebsite.com/**en/cosmetic-surgery/rhinoplasty-turkey**

Comment: Google doesn't care much about words in URLs for rankings.  Do what makes them best for users: descriptive enough but concise.

Comment: Is it necessary to put our main pillar pages in top level of URL?